# Проблема получения курса валют через soap

Tags: xml, php, soap

```
<?
$client = new SoapClient("http://nbrb.by/Services/ExRates.asmx?WSDL", array(
    "trace" => 1,
    "exceptions" => 0
));
$curs   = $client->ExRatesDyn(getSOAPDate(time()));

print_r($curs);

function getSOAPDate($timeStamp, $withTime = true)
{
    $soapDate = date("Y-m-d", $timeStamp);
    return ($withTime) ? $soapDate . "T" . date("H:i:s", $timeStamp) : $soapDate . "T00:00:00";
}
?>
```

Вот с таким кодом я пытался получить xml с курсами валют, но получил фигу. Хотя другие методы на этом же сервисе работают. Там где нет даты в качестве параметра.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по WSDL там 3 параметры, ИдВалюты, ДатаОт, ДатаК

вроде как...

```
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="curId" type="s:int"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="fromDate" type="s:dateTime"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="toDate" type="s:dateTime"/>
```

Comment: Неправильно указал метод, на самомом деле так ExRatesDaily
$curs   = $client->ExRatesDaily(getSOAPDate(time()));